# Creating JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this data with different classes and grades

```
{'Chemistry': 97.27, 'Civics': 100.0, 'History': 73.07}
```

How can I parse the data and create the json below?

```
   {
"class":{
    "Chemistry":{
          "grade":97.27
  }
},
"class":{
    "Civics":{
          "grade":100.0
}
},
"class":{
      "History":{
          "grade":73.07
}
}
   }
```

Comment: You can google for one of the many tools already written for it.

Comment: Which one do you recommend?

Comment: That is invalid `JSON` since you cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: look http://pymotw.com/2/json/

Comment: You could instead create a list of classes that _would_ be valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'Chemistry': 97.27, 'Civics': 100.0, 'History': 73.07}
>>> lst = [{ 'class': { k: { 'grade': v } } } for k, v in d.items()]
>>> lst
[{'class': {'Civics': {'grade': 100.0}}}, {'class': {'History': {'grade': 73.07}}}, {'class': {'Chemistry': {'grade': 97.27}}}]
>>> json.dumps(lst)
'[{"class": {"Civics": {"grade": 100.0}}}, {"class": {"History": {"grade": 73.07}}}, {"class": {"Chemistry": {"grade": 97.27}}}]'
>>> print(json.dumps(lst, indent=2))
[
  {
    "class": {
      "Civics": {
        "grade": 100.0
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "class": {
      "History": {
        "grade": 73.07
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "class": {
      "Chemistry": {
        "grade": 97.27
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the json module :

```
import json

dic = {u'Chemistry': 97.27, u'Civics': 100.0, u'History': 73.07}

str = json.dumps(dic)
print str
```

Output :

```
{"Civics": 100.0, "Chemistry": 97.27, "History": 73.07}
```

Comment: That output looks nothing like the expected (invalid) output from the OP.